# segmentation fault while using sprintf

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to write a simple device driver and application program to access the driver.

Driver write system call looks like this

```
static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *filp, const char *buff, size_t len, loff_t *off)
{
short c=0;
short ind =0;
short count=0;
memset(msg,0,100);
readPos=0;
while(len>0)
{
 msg[count++]=buff[ind++];
 len--;
}
```

and application program which works looks as follows

```
int main()
{
char buf[100];
char i = 0;
char tag=0;

int fp;
char *val[10];
char *rval[10];
unsigned int a =18440;
unsigned int d =1;
memset(buf, 0, 10);
tag=1;
fp = open("/dev/dd",O_RDWR);
if (fp<0)
{ 
  printf("file failed to open\n");
}  
sprintf(val[1],"%d%x%x",tag,a,d);
write(fp,val[1],strlen(val[1]));
sprintf(rval[1],"%d%x",tag,a);// statement that causes segmentation fault
return 0;
}
```

Now if I add one more sprintf function as shown above , it leads to segmentation fault.I do not know why?. If I remove this line, the code works fine. What could be the problem? The same problem happens when I call sprintf and write as a subfunction call?

Comment: Where is `msg` defined? What is it?  Was the compilation done with all warnings enabled?  Any warnings?

Comment: `val[1]`, a `char *`,  is given to `sprintf()` without a value assigned to it.  `sprintf(val[1],"%d%x%x",tag,a,d);` is receiving a garbage pointer.

Comment: `char *val[10];
char *rval[10];` --> `char val[24];char rval[24];`, `snprintf(val, sizeof(val), "%d%x%x",tag,a,d);` and so on.

Comment: Thank you reply. I admit, I am a beginner. Followed the example given as per the link https://appusajeev.wordpress.com/2011/06/18/writing-a-linux-character-device-driver/  . Write system call only accepts strings. This is the reason I have used sprintf. Please explain why the second sprintf leads to segmentation fault. The code works fine without the second sprintf

Comment: In what sense it works fine? The only reason the first sprintf did not cause a crash would be that val[1] happened to be NULL (and sprintf did not do anything) or it *happened* to point to something writable, which is extremely unlikely. The same circumstances are needed to survive the second sprintf and presumably they just don't hold. Again, sprintf expects a pointer to an area big enough to hold the resulting string. You pass a pointer to who-knows-what, since you don't initialize it. The outcome of the program is a complete accident. Please consult your fellow students.

Comment: As for the appusajeev.wordpress.com blog, as hopefully visible from my answer below, the resource is extremely bad and must not be used. Note that just because something gave you results you were possibly expecting and did not crash outright does not mean it is even remotely correct.

Comment: Problem solved with snprintf as suggested by bluepixy. Thank you. No more errors.

Comment: This is my last attempt to note that the code is of very poor quality and in fact works by accident. Good luck with your education if that's fine with you.

Answer (score 1):

Given the question asked and significant problems found elsewhere in the code, I take it you are a beginner C programmer, and possibly a beginner programmer in general. As such, I strongly recommend you don't play with kernel internals for the time being. It is significantly easier to write and debug userspace stuff.

I also have to note that comments which can be found below the question are peculiar to me in that they only address extremely minor points while ignoring the big picture.

First I'll handle the userspace part and then comment on the kernel code.

```
int main()
{
char buf[100];
```

In your actual code the code of the function starts at the beginning of the line as well? Typically people indent by at least 4 spaces, if not 8. Or a tab for that matter.

```
char i = 0;
```

Unused variable.

```
char tag=0;
```

Why is this being set to 0 here and why is the style different from the above line? (" = " vs "")

```
int fp;
```

File descriptors are commonly named 'fd'. 'fp' is used for things returned from e.g. fopen.

```
char *val[10];
char *rval[10];
unsigned int a =18440;
unsigned int d =1;
```

Yet another style of assignemnt.

```
memset(buf, 0, 10);
```

Why?

```
tag=1;
```

This overwrites the assignment in declaration.

```
fp = open("/dev/dd",O_RDWR);
if (fp<0)
{ 
  printf("file failed to open\n");
```

This should print the actual error received, e.g. with perror. Also note the program continues the execution despite the error.

```
}  
sprintf(val[1],"%d%x%x",tag,a,d);
```

As was correctly pointed out in one of the comments, the value of val[1] is unspecified and writing to that is undefined behaviour. Given the gravity of the problem, I think you need to re-read lessons about pointers and string handling.

```
write(fp,val[1],strlen(val[1]));
```

strlen is easily avoidable by capturing the return value of sprintf instead

```
sprintf(rval[1],"%d%x",tag,a);// statement that causes segmentation fault
```

Same problem as with the previous sprintf.

```
return 0;
}
```

Now the kernel part. While the pasted sample is incomplete, it is sufficient to see the module is wrong.

```
static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *filp, const char *buff, size_t len, loff_t *off)
{
short c=0;
short ind =0;
short count=0;
```

Why are these of type short? This is a problem as mentioned below. Also why are you setting them to 0 here?

```
memset(msg,0,100);
```

Why is the memset even executed?

It is not known what msg is, but the repeated 100 strongly hints the code is wrong. If this is a static buffer, sizeof(msg) should be used. Otherwise there should be either a macro or a variable with the size.

```
readPos=0;
```

This is very likely wrong.

```
while(len>0)
```

len was not validated with respect to buffer size, so in particular you can start writing past the buffer. Also note how having a dedicated way of expressing the buffer size would avoid another repetition of the number 100.

```
{
 msg[count++]=buff[ind++];
```

len is of type size_t, which is considerably longer than short, which is used for both count and ind. So in particluar for sizes bigger than ones representable with positive sign in short, this will in practice flip from +32k to -32k. That is, you will start writing stuff *prior* to the buffer. If that happens to not crash, you will repeat the cycle provided big enough len.

But that's really a minor point as the access to the userspace buffer is done incorrectly. To quote myself from elsewhere:
Access of this manner is a security and reliability threat. Consider what happens when the user passes an address of something within the kernel or is garbage. Also it will straight up not work in several cases (e.g. SMAP or architectures which have the kernel address space split from userspace).

You need to get_user, copy_from_user or similar.

```
 len--;
}
```